# by setting the charset in an iCalendar file

Tags: outlook, icalendar

I'm having trouble with accents in an iCalendar. Anyone happen to know how to set the charset in this file?

charset I want to set is this: test / calendar; method = REQUEST; charset = UTF-8

Icalender file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-Projuris Calendário
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:Projuris WEB (Administrador)
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/Sao_Paulo
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/Sao_Paulo
TZURL:http://tzurl.org/zoneinfo/America/Sao_Paulo
X-LIC-LOCATION:America/Sao_Paulo
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20130625T010000
DTEND:20130625T010000
ORGANIZER;CN=Projuris WEB (Administrador):MAILTO:networkservice@ache.com.br
UID:496254697
COMMENT;X-COMMENTER=MAILTO:networkservice@ache.com.br
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:
SUMMARY:   Pasta  12 
  Aditamento da Inícial Ação 

STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20130514T080000
DTEND:20130514T080000
ORGANIZER;CN=Projuris WEB (Administrador):MAILTO:networkservice@ache.com.br
UID:300843810
COMMENT;X-COMMENTER=MAILTO:networkservice@ache.com.br
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:
SUMMARY:   Assembléia  
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20130528T080000
DTEND:20130528T080000
ORGANIZER;CN=Projuris WEB (Administrador):MAILTO:networkservice@ache.com.br
UID:1152228998
COMMENT;X-COMMENTER=MAILTO:networkservice@ache.com.br
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:
SUMMARY:   Assembléia  
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the data in the UTF8 encoding. How do you construct the file?

Comment: Yes, I want to pass the charset within the file.

Answer (score 1):

well have a look at the RFC5545:

> 3.1.4.  Character Set
>
> There is not a property parameter to declare the charset used in a 
>   property value.  The default charset for an iCalendar stream is UTF-8 
>   as defined in [RFC3629].